# How to get size of map?

Tags: haxe

Is it possible to get map length/size? For some reason, I need to know the size of the map for debugging purposes.

I cant seem to do something like this:

```
map = new Map<Int, MyObject>();
map.set(.., ..);
map.set(.., ..);
map.length // should be 2
```

I hope this is possible. If its not, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Lambda.count(map)`.

But know that this will iterate through all values and might be expensive.

---

As to why there's no `length` property in the interface:

> Map implementation is rarely length-based so it's hard to know the length unless you maintain an additional counter for it, which in most of the cases is not useful.

—[Issue #1663: Size of *Map and other Data Structures (comment)](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1663#issuecomment-18531221)